# Button click on kendo detail template is not firing (button on child grid in hierarchical grid)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a hierarchical grid, on main grid i have a button on the top of the grid using toolbar template on click it opens the kendo window. This works perfectly fine. On the child grid I have to have the same functionality, where I have a button on the top of the child grid, On click of the button it should show the kendo window. But the button click on the child grid is not firing. Below is the code.

```
 /My main grid
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BHEBS.Areas.Admin.Models.ContractModel.providers>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Filterable(false).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorType);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BHSISNum);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StartDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorIsAlsoRegion);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorName);
            columns.Bound(p => p.AddressBkNum);

        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .Selectable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Contractors_Read", "Contract").Data("additionalInfo"))
        )

        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add k-primary" id="providerskendowindow">Add Providers</button>

        </div>
    </text>);
})

            )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//my child grid

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BHEBS.Areas.Admin.Models.ContractModel.serviceDetails>()
            .Name("grid_#=Id#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(50);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceId);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceType);
                columns.Bound(o => o.AdultChild);
                columns.Bound(o => o.IFGSwitch);
                columns.Bound(o => o.CodeModifier);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceModifier);
                columns.Bound(o => o.StartDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                columns.Bound(o => o.EndDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            })
             .ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add k-primary" id="serviceskendowindow">Add Services</button>
        </div>
    </text>);
})
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(10)
                      .Read(read => read.Action("Services_Read", "Contract", new { contractorId = "#=Id#" }))
                    )

                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .ToClientTemplate()

    )
</script>

//Main grid button click window

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("providerwindow")
    .Title("Add Business Units")
    .Content(@<text><div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BHEBS.Areas.Admin.Models.ContractModel.providers>()
        .Name("grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(x => { }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "chkbox" }).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id = 'chk' onclick='SetCheckBOX()' />");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Filterable(false).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorType);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BHSISNum);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StartDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorName);
        })
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable()
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:350px;" })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                                .Read(read => read.Action("Contractors_Read", "Contract").Data("additionalInfo"))
                )
                    )
                    <button class="k-button close-button k-primary" style="bottom: 10px; ">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="k-button k-primary" id="showSelection" style="bottom: 10px; ">Add</button>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div></text>
            )
            .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(800)

    .Visible(false) 
)

//Child grid button click kendo window

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("servicewindow")
    .Title("Add Business Units")
    .Content(@<text><div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BHEBS.Areas.Admin.Models.ContractModel.serviceDetails>()
        .Name("grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(x => { }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "chkbox" }).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id = 'chk' onclick='SetCheckBOX()' />");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Filterable(false).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ServiceId);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ServiceType);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StartDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.AdultChild);
        })
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable()
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:350px;" })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                                      .Read(read => read.Action("Services_Read", "Contract", new { contractorId = "#=Id#" }))
                )
                    )
                    <button class="k-button close-button k-primary" style="bottom: 10px; ">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="k-button k-primary" id="showSelection" style="bottom: 10px; ">Add</button>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div></text>
            )
            .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(800)

    .Visible(false)

)


<script>
    function additionalInfo() {
        var contractId =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ContractService.Id));
        return {
            Id: contractId
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#providerskendowindow").click(function(){
            alert("inside");
            $("#providerwindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        });
        $("#serviceskendowindow").click(function(){
            alert("inside");
            $("#servicewindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        });

    });
    $(".close-button").click(function(){
        // call 'close' method on nearest kendoWindow
        $(this).closest("[data-role=window]").kendoWindow("close");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that at the time you are binding the click event to your child window grid button, it does not exist in the DOM. Your child grid is defined inside a template that is dynamically built within your main grid as the page is rendered. You should change the syntax of your event binding to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#serviceskendowindow', function() {
  alert("inside");
  $("#servicewindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
});
```